# Parameter "@Fname" Has no default value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Sub Save()
        Try
            con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim cb As String = "insert into [Data] ([Fname],[Lname],[User],[Pass],[Birthday],[Role],[Pic]) VALUES (@Fname,@Lname,@Username,@Password,@Birthday,@Role,@Pic)"
            Dim i As New Integer
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Fname", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Fname"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Lname", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Lname"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@User", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Username"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Pass", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Password"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Birthday", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date, 250, "Birthday"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Role", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Role"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txt_Fname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txt_Lname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txt_User.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_Pass.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", CDate(Birthday.Value))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", cb_role.Text)


            Dim FileSize As New UInt32
            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Register_picture.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Dim picture() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer
            FileSize = mstream.Length
            mstream.Close()

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", picture)

            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                MsgBox("New User Register Succesfully!", vbInformation)
            Else
                MsgBox("New User Register Fail!", vbCritical)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your issue is because you're adding all the parameters twice; remove all the `AddWithValue` calls and then set the `Value` property on the `OleDbParameter` [read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.value?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to your values you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As well as adding the parameters twice, the way you're adding them the first time is wrong. The fourth parameter is the name of the source column in the `DataTable` when you call `Update`, which you're not doing. Get rid of this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Fname", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Fname"))
```

and this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txt_Fname.Text)
```

and replace them with this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", OleDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = txt_Fname.Text
```

You only need to specify a size for data types that have a size, e.g. `varchar` and `varbinary`. You don't need one for `date`:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(Birthday.Value)
```

What is `Birthday` in that context? That it has a `Value` property suggests that it is a `DateTimePicker`, in which case that `Value` property is already type `Date`, so using `CDate` is pointless. What you probably ought to do is zero the time though:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", OleDbType.Date).Value = Birthday.Value.Date
```

I'd also suggest changing the name `Birthday`. That name suggests that it is a `Date` variable that actually contains a birthday. I'd also suggest that "date of birth" is a more appropriate term than "birthday". The former generally means the actual day you were born while the latter generally means the anniversary of that day in any subsequent year. As such, I'd name that control `dateOfBirthPicker`. Now the name is accurate and descriptive, unlike `Birthday`. That assumes that I am correct in what it actually is.